Rabbi who made a deal with the devil
I've heard over a number of years, a legend of a certain (middle-ages) rabbi who made a deal with the devil in order to save his community.
More details than that:
I seem to record that there was a plague in his community,
I seem to recall the name "Baal Shem of Chelm",
I seem to recall that there was a dubious link to the reciting of Psalm 27 between 1st Elul and Hoshana Raba.
Does anyone have more details? To be clear, I don't care if this was considered a total myth and was debunked several times, I'm just looking for a source.
This question may exist already on this site but I couldn't find it after a few searches. If this info already exists, I'm more than happy for you to link the duplicate and close the question...

R. Eliyahu the Ba'al Shem of Chelm was a real person in the 1500s (and the great-grandfather of R. Emden). He is usually associated with the golem story before that was (somewhat illogically) transfered to the Maharal of Prague. Variations of the Faust legend have been floating around European folklore for centuries.  That could be all that was needed to make a legend.

Not that it matches any of the conditions , but Simon Kippah made a deal with the devil in a sense https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_Aggada_of_Shimon_Kippa,Aggada_of_Shimon_Kippa(Version_3)&ved=2ahUKEwiioeWc59uHAxW0QEEAHU_PHiAQFnoECBgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1LXZeH9iR1QFiohmbZjkLY

From the lecture by Dr Shnayer Leiman (linked by @Efraym): The Sefer Nezer Hakodesh of Ropshitz mentions a tradition not to say Psalm 27 in Elul or the kabalistic paragraph "kegavna" on Friday night.
These customs were attributed to the Ba'al Shem of Chelm, and as a punishment for making a deal with Satan himself, it was decided that the customs he created should be cancelled.
The story goes that the local ruler threatened to banish all Jews from his land unless they prayed for him to have a child, and the Ba'al Shem could not receive approval from Heaven so he turned to Hell instead.
The story considers this as an act of heroism, that he was willing to forfeit his eternity for the sake of his fellow Jews, rather than a betrayal of Judaism.

Rabbi Dr. Shnayer Leiman in a lecture on why we say L'Dovid Hashem Ori discusses this story. I don't remember off hand all the details.

He quotes the "nezer hakodesh" of Ropshitz.
